# How to use Blazor to send email thru Azure website

Tags: azure-web-app-service, blazor

If I am creating a Blazor App base on Asp.net Host template and I have a paid subscription for Azure. I would like to know how to send an email when user have entered the required info.

Here the code for Asp.netCore and I am not sure how to use it for my case using Blazor to send thru Azure website. Would appreciate if you can provide some reference to read or a sample code to try out.
Thanks

```
using System.Net.Mail;

MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("email1@somewebsite.com");
mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("email2@somewebsite.com"));
mailMessage.Subject = "Your subject";
mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
mailMessage.Body = "Email body";
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("email1@somewebsite.com", "password");
client.Host = "smtpout.asia.secureserver.net";
client.Send(mailMessage);
```

Comment: In the Hosted model, you will have to run this from the server-side. That requires a Web-API call from Bazor first. And then your code might just work, if all the config is correct.

Comment: This is not related to `Blazor` in a specific way. The implementation would be the same for a simple ASP application. The code, if configured correctly, would work in the `Blazor` client-side model as well, though with the risk that it could be reverse engineered to reveal sensitive config. That is why you might want to have a hosted web API in between.

Comment: I found many said it is not good to use SendGrid from Azure.  But I have no idea where to begin as my blazor-Website is hosted in Azure. I need a sample code to follow and I learned it was not the same as asp.net the usual way. I dont seem to find any example for this blazor. Thanks